# Programming a Discord bot in Python- Why can't the bot send custom emojis?

Tags: python, discord.py

Here's what I have:

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, text):
    catjam = client.get_emoji(799738295520591873)
    await ctx.send(f"{catjam}{text}{catjam}")
```

The result I want is to send the user's message, with the emoji on either side. Instead it does this:[image]

And yes, there are questions like this that have been asked, but I looked at those and none of them helped with my problem. Any tips?

Comment: if you can type the emoji into discord, e.g. something like `:catjam:`, that should work if you sent the text as well.

Comment: What intents have you enabled? Are you sure you're copying the ID correctly?

Comment: Yes, the ID is correct. Not sure what you mean by _intents_

Comment: Is this emoji in the same server as your bot? Bots can't use emojis if they don't share a server (like how a nitro user can't use an emoji unless they're in a specific server).

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to make a bot sending a certain emote you need to do like this <:emote_name:emote_ID> ( if it's animated add "a" after < )  And, in order to work, you must have that emote in your server or to be in a server that contains that emote, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Yeah the emote is in the server, but the bot just keeps saying :catjam: instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks to everyone for your help. You were all right I just didn't have the correct id...

Answer (score 3):

To do a custom emoji, you would do `<:name_of_emoji:id_of_emoji>`. e.g `<:pepe:1262321934>`

In Code:
`await ctx.send("<:pepe:1262321934>")`

Comment: Hmm I tried this out, it just says :catjam: instead of sending the emote.

Comment: @CarterMichaelis It has to be from your server, it cannot be from a remote server. Sometimes it works from a remote server and sometimes it does not.